# Integrate embedded CSV file - PHP

Tags: php, html, csv, search

I am trying to integrate a embedded CSV file via PHP using a form search.

My CSV looks like this:

```
ACCTNO        PRCLID    NOTICES
00109033-01   234962    2056, 3005, 1033
00104120-04   200921    2006, 3002, 3004, 2056, 1033
00170172-01   299573    2056, 3001, 3003, 3004, 1033
00106284-02   208709    1026, 2056, 3004, 1033
00150372-01   222376    2056, 3001, 2006, 1033
```

Basically I am trying to have a search box where the user enters 00109033-01, and a the three divs that correspond to 2056, 3005 and 1033 (from the 'NOTICES' column) are presented. If the user searched for 00104120-04 the five divs that correspond to 2006, 3002, 3004, 2056, 1033 (from the 'NOTICES' column) are presented.

I will have corresponding divs for each of the 'NOTICE' codes, some relate to an account, others don't.

I know how to embed CSV data but I am struggling to workout the interrogation part and presenting the corresponding divs.

Any hints, code help or even just the right terminology for what I am trying to achieve would be a great help.

Comment: import csv in to db, then it will be easy

Comment: Loop through all the rows in the CSV, and compare `$row[0]` with the user input. When it matches, display the information from `$row[2]`.

Comment: see [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) in PHP >= 5.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it using [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).

```
<?php
// will hold account number to search for
$acctno = isset($_GET['acctno']) ? $_GET['acctno'] : null; 
// will hold the notices that are found
$notices = null; 
// check if account number was given
if ($acctno) {
    // open the CSV file for reading
    if ($file = fopen('file.csv', 'r')) {
        // loop through rows of CSV file searching for account number
        while (($data = fgetcsv($file)) !== false) {
            // if there is a match, save its corresponding notices and stop looping
            if ($data[0] === $acctno) {
                $notices = $data[2];
                break;
            }
        }
        // close the CSV file
        fclose($file);
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="get">
        <label>Search</label>
        <input type="text" name="acctno" value="<?= $acctno ?>">
    </form>
    <p><?= $notices ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you all and especially to Mikey... Although I wasn't specifically asking for a working example, it is hugely appreciated and it works beautifully. Many thanks